# Upgrading boto2 to boto3: block_device_mapping structure

Tags: python-3.x, upgrade, boto, boto3

I am currently upgrading an old code using boto2 and I want to use boto3. A part of the old code is this:

```
EC2 = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1", **AUTH)
AMI = EC2.get_all_images(owners="297649722856")
amiList = []
for image in AMI:
    ami_snapshot_id = image.block_device_mapping.current_value.snapshot_id
    amiList.append(ami_snapshot_id)
```

My issue is about how to get the snapshot_id of the block_device_mapping. I've gone through the documentation of both boto2 and boto3 and I didn't find how to upgrade this.

Is there a way to have the same function in boto3?